# Authentication in directory using mysql and apache is not working

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, apache2.4

I am using mysql 5.7.22 and apache2.4.29 for directory authentication in webpages.

Here is my config for apache.

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html/private>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        AuthName "Enter your credential"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider dbd
        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT authentication_string FROM user WHERE User=%s"
        Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

This is apache2 error.log.

```
[Sat Jul 21 12:57:12.005948 2018] [auth_basic:error]AH01617: 
user testuser: authentication failure for "/~testuser/private": 
Password Mismatch
```

I have tried entered the right password. I tried changing passwords several times and testing the login but could not get it work.

Comment: Is `mod_authn_dbd` loaded?

Answer (score 0):

What hashing you using for your password? needs to be sha1base64 or md5